# How to update latex bibliography properly

Tags: reference, latex, bibliography, biblatex, texlipse

I used texlipse plugin in eclipse for latex, and copied the references from bibteX google scholar in bibliography.bib
But when i generate PDF, it doesn't have all the references i added to bibliography. How to update the bibliography properly

Comment: You've got to also run bibtex on your file... See [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/5764).

Comment: seems like a stupid clarification, however, 0. i assume you haven't messed with the build configuration/builder settings in texlipse. 1. have you enabled automatic build on texlipse? 2. have you saved the bib file? If these conditions are true, I don't understand why it should not work.

Comment: of course, if the bib entry from google scholar has some errors (like many from springer have an underscore, which have to be explictly escaped) it won't compile properly

Comment: if above options does not work, run it once in Terminal or any other editor, post a MWE and error. This will help to identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have used <kbd>F11</kbd> two times to update the bib and it worked for me. you may need to press <kbd>F11</kbd> multiple times.

Comment: Any idea why you need two times?

Answer (score -1):

If you use TexMaker, after adding citation dont forget to re-run your BibTex file (.BibTex) using F11, then run the TEX file. It works in my case.